# Recurrent neural networks patterns distinguishing

Tags: neural-network

Is possible to distinguish between patterns `[ABCDEFG]` and `[ABCDEGF]`? And What about distinguishing between `[ABCDEFGH]` and `[BCDEFGH]`?

Answer (score 1):

I did a PhD entitled "Temporal Sequence Processing In neural Networks". It contains many ideas for solving exactly this type of question. You can download it [here](http://www.reiss.demon.co.uk/misc/m_reiss_phd.pdf). Chapter 9 concerns the recognition of sequences, though it will probably refer to a great many things covered in earlier chapters, so I'm not sure you can read that on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).